# EmberJS - Accessing items in an array from the view

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I am trying to set the selection binding of an `Ember.Select` to an object in an array held in the controller.

Firstly, following a button click, a new item is added to the array in the controller.

```
this.get('myArray').pushObject(newlyCreatedObject);
```

Then the view is pushed into a `Ember.ContainerView` as follows via an action on the controller:

```
Ember.View.views[this.get('myViewContainer')].pushObject(
  App.MyView.create({ arrayIndex: this.get('myArray.length')-1});
)
```

The inserted view correctly holds the property `arrayIndex` but I cannot work out how to reference the item in `myArray` in my controller from the `MyView` handlebars template.

I have tried `selection=myArray.[view.arrayIndex].propertyOfObject` on the `Ember.Select` but it doesn't work, though no exceptions are thrown.

Thanks.

Comment: i doubt if we can reference item of an array directly..you have to do a workaround creating computed properties and observers...

Comment: Can you create a failing bin?

Comment: Thanks for taking a look. After plenty of head scratching I have created a workaround where I pass the required element of `myArray` into the view during create(). `App.MyView.create({ myObject: this.get('myArray').objectAt(index) });`